# How to use functions to do a recursive calculation in data.table/R?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, for-loop, data.table

I am new to Programming and got stuck in it. I wanted to calculate the hourly temperature variation of an object throughout the year using some variables, which changes in every hour. The original data contains 60 columns and 8760 rows for the calculation.

I got the desired output using the `for` loop, but the model is taking a lot of time for the calculation. I wonder if there is any way to replace the loop with functions, which I suspect, can also increase the speed of the calculations.

Here is a small reproducible example to show what I did.

```
table <- data.table("A" = c(1), "B" = c(1:5), "C" = c(10))

table
```

```
   A B  C
1: 1 1 10
2: 1 2 10
3: 1 3 10
4: 1 4 10
5: 1 5 10
```

The `for`loop

```
for (j in (2: nrow(table))) {
  table$A[j] = (table$A[j-1] + table$B[j-1]) * table$B[j]
  table$C[j] = table$B[j] * table$A[j] 
 }
```

I got the output as I desired:

```
     A B    C
1:   1 1   10
2:   4 2    8
3:  18 3   54
4:  84 4  336
5: 440 5 2200
```

but it took 15 min to run the whole program in my case (not this!)

So I tried to use function instead of the `for` loop.

I tried this:

```
table <- data.table("A" = c(1), "B" = c(1:5), "C" = c(10))


myfun <- function(df){
  df = df %>% mutate(A = (lag(A) + lag(B)) * B, 
                     C = B * A)
  return(df)
}

myfun(table)
```

But the output was

```
   A B   C
1 NA 1  NA
2  4 2   8
3  9 3  27
4 16 4  64
5 25 5 125
```

As it seems that the function refers to the rows of the first table not the updated rows after the calculation. Is there any way to obtain the desired output using functions?  It is my first R project, any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I guess this is just a toy example but if not  `A` will grow very fast... O(n!) numbers will very soon get too big.

Comment: Yes, this example is just to understand the possible ways. With the Answers I would like to reprogram my model and will definitely update the results.

Answer (score 3):

A much faster alternative using `data.table`. Note that the calculation of `C` can be separated from the calculation of `A` so we can do less within the loop:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(table)) {
  set(table, i = i, j = "A", value = with(table, (A[i-1] + B[i-1]) * B[i]))
}
table[-1, C := A * B]
table

#        A     B     C
#    <num> <int> <num>
# 1:     1     1    10
# 2:     4     2     8
# 3:    18     3    54
# 4:    84     4   336
# 5:   440     5  2200
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `purrr::accumulate2` which lets you use the result of the previous computation as the input to the next one:

```r
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

table <- data.table("A" = c(1), "B" = c(1:5), "C" = c(10))

table$A <- accumulate2(
  table$A,
  seq(table$A),
  ~ (..1 + table$B[..3]) * table$B[..3 + 1],
  .init = table$A[1]
) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  extract(1:nrow(table))
  
table$C <- table$B * table$A

table
#      A B    C
# 1:   1 1    1
# 2:   4 2    8
# 3:  18 3   54
# 4:  84 4  336
# 5: 440 5 2200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Reduce` like below

```
dt[
  ,
  A := Reduce(function(x, Y) (x + Y[2]) * Y[1],
    asplit(embed(B, 2), 1),
    init = A[1],
    accumulate = TRUE
  )
][
  ,
  C := A * B
]
```

which updates `dt` as

```
> dt
     A B    C
1:   1 1    1
2:   4 2    8
3:  18 3   54
4:  84 4  336
5: 440 5 2200
```

##### data

```
dt <- data.table("A" = c(1), "B" = c(1:5), "C" = c(10))
```